# socket io and cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, sockets

I want to create a Cordova app for android that communicates with nodejs server. Here's my code:

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect('ws://HEROKUHOST');
   console.log(socket);
   socket.send('hi');
});
```

Server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("Connected");

  socket.on('message', function () { console.log("GOT MESSSS")});
});
```

It works locally in browser, but in app it does connect but doesn't send the message. 
So, on server I revieve "Connected" message on connection, but socket.on('message') is never calling. I thing there is something blocking  *socket.send('hi')*.

Answer (score 0):

Is your nodejs server live? I guess hosted on Heroku right?
Do this change to your code:
In cordova code:

var socket = io.connect('HEROKUHOST');

console.log(socket);

socket.emit('message',{});

});

Means no need to use ws:// before your URL. Keep it simple https url. Secondly instead of socket.send use socket.emit
Also socket.send is used at server side, not client side. Client calls event "message" which is than send from server using socket.send("Hi")

Hope it helps

Comment: Emit also does not work, the app connects to server (socket.connected is true), but there is no communication between them. I've tested ws (WebSockets) and it works, but unfortunately i need socket.io connection.
I'd be glad to have an example of socket.io communication that works on cordova.

Comment: What is the version of socket you are using on server and on client as well?

Answer (score 0):

For me , the problem was because of upgrading server side packages specially socket.io
..  after hours of searching I decided to downgrade to be adapted with client version, then the problem was solved.